# SORM vs MySQL idle connection

Tags: mysql, jdbc, playframework, c3p0, sorm

I'm using **Play Framework 2.2.1**, **MySQL 5.5** and **sorm 0.3.10**

Since MySQL drops inactive connections after specified idle timeout, I'm getting this exception in my app:

```
[CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was 162 701 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.]
```

As far as I understand, sorm is using c3p0 connection pool. Is it possible to configure somehow c3p0 or sorm to kick mysql with specified delay or reconnect automatically after connection was dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.3.13-SNAPSHOT` of SORM introduces a `timeout` parameter for `Instance` with a default setting of `30`. This setting determines the amount of seconds the underlying connections are allowed to be idle. When the timeout is reached a sort of a "keepalive" request is sent to the db and the timer is reset. The timer gets reset when any normal query is made as well. The implementation simply relies on the `idleConnectionTestPeriod` of C3P0.

For further discussion, suggestions and reports please visit [the associated ticket on the issue tracker](https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/37) or open another one. If there'll be no complaints in [the associated ticket](https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/37), this change will make it into the 0.3.13 release.

Answer (score 1):

it's very easy to resolve this issue with c3p0, but i'd double check whether you are using it. BoneCP is the default play2 Connection pool. it would be easy to solve this problem with BoneCP too!

in c3p0, config params [maxIdleTime](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxIdleTime), [maxConnectionAge](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxConnectionAge), or (much better yet) a Connection testing regime, would help. see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

if you want to use c3p0 in play2, see https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0-play

Comment: Well, sorm depends on c3p0, and I wont be surpised if it will conflict with play plugin.

Comment: if you want so see whether c3p0 is actually the pool your app uses, look in the log files for a dump of your pool's config at pool initialization (or else have your VM dump threads, and look for c3p0-related Threads, or use JMX to see if any c3p0 pools are in use).

Comment: Sorm uses c3p0 internally.

Comment: So is it possible to configure it somehow?

Comment: @SergeyLiar I've opened a [related ticket](https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/37) on the issue tracker with the information on possible workarounds. We should continue the discussion there.

Comment: if c3p0 is in use, you can always find ways to configure it. if you define a c3p0.properties file in the top level of your classpath, unless SORM overrides the config that you set explicitly, the config there will take. you can configure c3p0 via System properties, an XML file, a typesafe-config/HOCON file, or programmatically. you can get access to SORM internal c3p0 DataSources via the [C3P0Registry](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/C3P0Registry.html) class.

Comment: Please do see [c3p0's config file documentation](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration_files). [HOCON / typesafe-config is only available in 0.9.5 prereleases; c3p0.properties and XML config go back a long way.]